# Phonegap Android App - Display Store MP3 Media

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I've been following this blog to help me make a simple music player function with an Android app (http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-media-class-in-phonegap.html).

All works well - but I would like some way to extract a list of all music media stored on the phone so the user can click a file and play it.  Does anyone know if this is possible via phone gap?  I'd need to access track name/artist etc and a link to the track.

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Hey Paul, I'm actually the guy who wrote that blog post. I've been considering revisiting it for awhile to do exactly what you want. There are two possible approaches:

1) Use the File API to list all the .mp3's in the Music directory then figure out some way to read the .mp3's meta data.

2) Write a plugin to query the media store for .mp3 files as I believe the data is stored in there.

Both are going to require writing some native Java code.

Comment: Cheers Simon - I'll await your blog update then!  & Thanks for the initial blog - its been very helpful.

Comment: Not sure when I will get to it. Perhaps it will be part of the book I'm hoping to write.

Comment: Hey Simon, Any update on your book ;) waiting for it. Got stuck while writhing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817625/phonegap-1-5-android-custom-plugin-to-access-media-library-get-all-artist-na

Answer (score 1):

Prognosis is not good.... PhoneGap does not have an API for accessing the media library.  So, you would have to fall back to the File API to locate music files, and then... you would have to read the binary data in the actual files to extract out the track/artist metadata.  Ouch.  Seems pretty impractical.

[EDIT]

By the way, PhoneGap is not the only game in town.  [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) seems to solve the same problem, and apparently has a richer API, which includes
[access to media metadata](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Media.Item-object.html)